# Create and run Python program with a Python program

Tags: python, file

This is my first time using Python and I'm trying to create a program that can:

1. Create a new Python program in IDLE
2. Make the new program contain the print command - print('Hello, world!')
3. Save the program and run it
4. Exit IDLE

This is the code I have so far. It doesn't seem to be creating the file, and I might have made some other mistakes that I don't know about.

```
import sys

name = input('C:\\MyFolder\\program.py')

//Create program containing print command
file = open(name, 'w')
file.write("print('Hello, world!')")
file.close()

//Run program (and possibly save it?)
os.system('C:\\MyFolder\\program.py')

//Exit IDLE
sys.exit(0)
```

How do I create, write to and run the new program?

Comment: What do you type as a response to that `input`? If you're just hitting return, then `name` is going to be empty; the argument to `input` is just a prompt, not a default value.

Comment: As a side note, you really shouldn't use `os.system`. Read the help or docs for it; notice that it suggests using `subprocess`. In this case, what you probably want is `subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, 'C:\\MyFolder\]program.py'])`.

Comment: One more thing: You're creating a file named whatever `name` is, but then trying to run a file named `C:\\MyFolder\\program.py`. So if the user types anything else at all, it's not going to find that file. You probably wanted to run `name` instead of `'C:\\MyFolder\\program.py'`.

Comment: And one more thing, on that comment about "and possibly save it?": You've _already_ saved it in the previous three lines. Running it won't affect that in any way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it isn't *entirely* clear from your question, I think I know what your problem is.

First, when you do `input('C:\\MyFolder\\program.py')`, that `C:\\MyFolder\\program.py` is just the prompt that gets displayed to the user. It's not a default value. So, if the user just hits return, `name` is going to be empty, and you're not going to successfully create a file.

Second, even if the user does type something, unless what he types is exactly `C:\\MyFolder\\program.py`, you're creating a file with one name, then trying to run a file with a different name, which isn't going to work.

So, you probably want something like this:

```
default_name = 'C:\\MyFolder\\program.py'
name = input(default_name)
if not name:
    name = default_name

# ... your existing code to create the file

os.system(name)
```

There are a lot of ways you could improve this (use `subprocess.check_call` with `sys.executable`, add a shbang line to the file, use a `with` statement instead of explicit `close`, make the prompt look something like `Filename (default C:\MyFolder\program.py)?` instead of just the default value, …). But this should be enough to get it working.